# How to add an exe to Linux global path?

Tags: linux, path, sudo

I'm building a tool chain (called dshell) which allows users to write cli scripts using Dart.

By default dart installs apps into ~/.pub-cache/bin

Dshell scripts use a shebang
... env dshell

The problem is that if you try run a dshell script using Sudo then the shebang doesn't work as dshell isn't on the root user's path.

So the question is which path should I install dshell into so it works with Sudo?

I suspect that I will have a second problem in that the dependency cache is also in the users home directory. Not certain how to handle that either.

Answers on how to do the same for MAC OS and windows would be useful.

Comment: Not familiar with that tooling - are there other directories under `~/.pub-cache`, namely `lib`?  One common way to achieve what you're looking for under Linux (and MacOS) is to place everything in the respective directory structure under `/usr/local`

Comment: Even though the topic deals with a tool that is related to Dart, this question has nothing to do with the Dart programming language, and the details of the tool itself are irrelevant to the question asked. You should probably remove the dart tag.

Comment: @tink .pub-cache/bin is a single directory however it's managed by the dart install so I can't move it but I could create a Slym link to it.